# How to change doctrine entity property in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Post entity with property 'content' type string. I need to change it type to text. 
What steps should I make to do so? I'm using Symfony 4.

Comment: Assuming you're using doctrine. You have to change annotation above content property and set it's type to text, than if you're using Symfony plugin and PHPStorm just generate getters and setters or write them on your own. At the end run schema:update --force Anyway this question needs more info to answer it like what ORM are you using

Answer (score 1):

Change annotation in your entity class

before:

```
// src/Entity/Foo.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $bar;
}
```

after:

```
// src/Entity/Foo.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $bar;
}
```

and run in root project
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f`

https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class

Answer (score 0):

Open up your `Post` entity located in `Entity`, then search for `content` and change `string` to `text` then make schema update on your DB to make changes in DB.